# Resultado equivocado en mi consulta de SQL

Tags: php, sql

Estoy tratando de extraer la cantidad de mensajes no leído que existen en cada conversación pero este me esta lanzando un valor equivocado, ya que el primer usuario solo me ha enviado 5 mensajes que yo no he leído y los demás solo me han enviado cada uno un solo mensaje. Pero por alguna razón que desconozco como resultado me esta sacando 6 mensajes no leídos en cada conversación.

[image: Captura de pantalla para mostrar el resultado]

He colocado la consulta en el SQL de **phpMyAdmin** y he descubierto que este me esta sacando la respuesta de forma correcta mas sin embargo a mi me esta sacando en todos los resultados de las conversaciones el número **6** NOTA: la primera conversación tiene 6 mensajes no leídos y yo creo que es allí donde esta el problema

[image: Resultados de phpMyAdmin]

### Nota importante:

En el código **SQL** que he colocado abajo, estoy sacando las conversaciones del usuario correctamente, el problema solo esta en que no logro sacar los mensajes no leídos que tiene cada usuario para ser mostrada como una notificación. Anteriormente estaba intentando sacar estos mensaje no leídos usando otra sentencia SQL en un archivo diferente, pero no tenia éxito porque donde tengo que sacar dicha información es el mismo sitio estoy sacando los mensajes.

En la tabla `messege` hay un campo llamado `view` que posee un dato que varía dependiendo su estado. Si el dato es igual a `No` es porque el mensaje no ha sido leído, si el `view = 'Si'` entonces es porque el mensaje fue leído.

### Tabla messege:

```
CREATE TABLE messege(
id_messege           int(255) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
id_emisor            int(255) NOT NULL,
id_receptor          int(255) NOT NULL,
messege              text,
photo_messege        varchar(200),
ip_messege           varchar(200),
browser_messege      varchar(200),
view                 varchar(50),
create_at_messege    datetime,
CONSTRAINT fk_messege_emisor FOREIGN KEY(id_emisor) REFERENCES users(id_user),
CONSTRAINT fk_messege_receptor FOREIGN KEY(id_receptor) REFERENCES users(id_user)
)ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

### Mi objetico:

Quiero mostrar la cantidad de mensajes no leídos que tengo en cada conversación

### Código SQL que emplee:

```
<?php
 // Sacar los usuarios con los que he tenido una conversacion
 $stetament = $conexion->prepare(
    "SELECT `id_user`, id_emisor, name, surname, photo_profile,
    create_at_messege, messege, view
    FROM (
      SELECT id_user,
        MAX(id_messege) id_messege
        FROM (
          SELECT id_receptor id_user,
            id_messege
            FROM messege
            WHERE id_emisor = $id
          UNION
          SELECT id_emisor id_user,
            id_messege
            FROM messege
            WHERE id_receptor = $id
        ) c1 GROUP BY 1  
    ) c2 JOIN messege USING(id_messege)
    JOIN users USING(id_user)
    ORDER BY id_messege DESC"
);

$stetament->execute(array());
$result = $stetament->fetchAll();
```

[image: Consulta SQL del comentario]

Comment: Hola @BetaM como podría hacerlo! Funciona mi logica como lo estoy haciendo a parte de no ver colocado el `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: Debido a que `user_id` no es un campo de la tabla `messege` he intelpretado y he colocado `id_messege`. Pero ahora en vez de 6 mensajes no leído me esta sacando 1 mensaje no leído que cada conversación lo cual quiere decir que sigue errónea la sentencia **SQL**

Comment: Deseas saber como esta estructurada la tabla `messege` o necesita algún otro dato para solucionar el problema  ?

Comment: Sin saber la estructura de la tabla, ¿Por qué no haces la consulta directamente y luego simplemente cuentas los registros devueltos con `$countMessege = count($result);`?

Comment: He colocado el `$countMessege = count($result);` y ahora me esta notificando 4 mensajes en cada conversación

Comment: @DigiSoul Creo que hay un problema y no se debe a mi consulta de **SQL** porque acabo de colocar la sentencia en el SQL de **phpMyAdmin** y allí me esta lanzado todos los datos correctos.

Comment: Cuelga un pantallazo de la consulta y los resultados a traves de phpMyAdmin y el valor de $resultado de tu consulta y podremos ver la diferencia.

Comment: @DigiSoul Ya he editado la pregunta

Comment: Me falta el contenido de la variable $resultado en tu consulta, para ver lo que te está devolviendo tu código. De todas formas, prueba a añadirle un GROUP BY id_messege al final de la consulta a ver que te resultado te da.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121085/discussion-between-braylin-ivan-payano-and-digisoul).

Comment: Agrega a tu pregunta el resultado de `SELECT id_emisor, view, group_concat(id_messege) FROM messege WHERE id_receptor = ? GROUP BY id_emisor, view`.

Comment: @Sal He publicado la captura con el resultado de la sentencia SQL de tu comentario

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu estrategia actual es un poco mas complicada de lo necesario, todo lo que necesitas sale con esta consulta:

```
SELECT t.*
     , um.create_at_messege
     , um.messege
     , um.view
  FROM ( SELECT u.id_user
              , m.id_emisor
              , u.name
              , u.surname
              , u.photo_profile
              , count( if( m.view = 'No', 1, null) ) countMessege
              , max(m.id_messege) ultimo_id_messege
           FROM messege m
             INNER JOIN users u
               ON u.id_user = m.id_emisor
           WHERE m.id_receptor = $id
           GROUP BY m.id_emisor
       ) t
   INNER JOIN messege um
     ON um.id_messege = t.ultimo_id_messege
```

Con esto puedes desechar `count-messege.php`, ya que el `SELECT` interior cuenta los mensajes a la vez que obtiene el id del mas reciente, con el cual se obtiene en el `SELECT`  exterior el contenido y fecha del último mensaje.

Para complementar con el último mensaje enviado, obtenemos en una consulta escalar el id del último mensaje enviado; en la consulta exterior discernimos cuál mensaje es mas reciente (el enviado o el recibido) con base en el valor del id, el mas alto es el mas reciente.

```
SELECT t.*
     , if( t.ultimo_id_messege_rec > t.ultimo_id_messege_env
         , umr.create_at_messege
         , ume.create_at_messege
         ) create_at_messege
     , if( t.ultimo_id_messege_rec > t.ultimo_id_messege_env
         , umr.messege
         , ume.messege
         ) messege
     , if( t.ultimo_id_messege_rec > t.ultimo_id_messege_env
         , umr.view
         , ume.view
         ) view
  FROM ( SELECT u.id_user
              , m.id_emisor
              , u.name
              , u.surname
              , u.photo_profile
              , count( if( m.view = 'No', 1, null) ) countMessege
              , max(m.id_messege) ultimo_id_messege_rec
              , ( SELECT max(id_messege)
                    FROM messege
                    WHERE id_emisor = $id
                      AND id_receptor = m.id_emisor
                ) ultimo_id_messege_env
           FROM messege m
             INNER JOIN users u
               ON u.id_user = m.id_emisor
           WHERE m.id_receptor = $id
           GROUP BY m.id_emisor
       ) t
   LEFT JOIN messege umr
     ON umr.id_messege = t.ultimo_id_messege_rec
   LEFT JOIN messege ume
     ON ume.id_messege = t.ultimo_id_messege_env
```

Comment: El problema es que al desechar `count-messege.php` me esta lanzando un error ya que la sentencia donde muestro los mensajes es muy diferente a esta

Comment: Ya he colocado la sentencia como me la has colocado aquí. Pero solo hay un problemita con el campo `view` que no me esta mostrando nada por pantalla

Comment: Me faltó esa columna @Braylin, ya la agregué.

Comment: Ha funcionado mejor que como yo la tenia antes, pero ya solo hay 2 problemas. Ahora dice que tengo 18 mensajes sin leer en la primera conversación, en la segunda 4, en la tercera 1 que esa si esta correcta y en la quinta 3. En realidad yo tengo 10 mensajes sin leer por todo, pero en la primera solo sin 6 mensajes sin leer y en las demás conversaciones tengo de ha 1 solo mensaje sin leer. Hay un error en la sentencia **SQL** verdad

Comment: Corre el `SELECT` interno en phpMyAdmin agregando la columna: `, group_concat( if(m.view='No',m.id_message,null) ) ids`. Con eso obtendrás la lista de ids de mensajes no leídos; revisa -por ejemplo- la quinta conversación, con los ids ubica los dos mensajes sobrantes y comparte los datos y/o dinos si notas algo.

Comment: Ya he hecho lo que me dijiste, pero no puedo mostrarte el resultado porque aun no se habrá la opción del chat para enviarte la captura de pantalla

Comment: Mas que mostrar el resultado, importa que nos digas -en términos de columnas y valores- por qué tal registro **no** debe incluirse en el conteo. Asumiendo que el valor de `view` es `No`.

Comment: Porque en el conteo si `view = 'No'` entonces quiere decir que es un mensaje no leído y se supone que en cada conversación se debe mostrar los mensajes que la otra persona ha enviado y que no se han leído

Comment: @BraylinIvanPayano Para resolver este tipo de situaciones de la mejor manera, convendría compartir un pequeño set de datos en la pregunta y la estructura de las tablas. Y si puede ser un fiddle para hacer pruebas mucho mejor. No debe ser algo difícil, pero sin tener a mano herramientas que muestren un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable se hace más complicado para poder responder. En sitios como [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) u otros es muy fácil subir un set de datos con cada tabla implicada.

Comment: @A.Cedano Perfecto. Voy a editar la pregunta para poner una estructura de como están estructurado los datos de la tabla con ejemplos

Comment: No se mucho como utilizar la web que me dejaste en el comentario pero voy a tratar de investigarla un poco

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta y he colocado la estructura de la tabla `messege`

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya esta hecho el sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a6c585/1

Comment: Hice una corrección, prueba con la consulta actualizada.

Comment: @Sal Ahora si se soluciono la pregunta. Muchas gracias mi querido amigo

Comment: @Sal Ahora que me acabo de dar cuenta. Solo hay un detalle en la conversaciones no me muestra el ultimo mensaje que yo como **Receptor** he recibido, solo me muestra el ultimo mensaje el el **Emisor** me envió a mi. Chequéame eso en la consulta por favor

Comment: @Braylin : Respuesta actualizada.

Comment: @Sal Hay dos pequeños problemas que no he logrado solucionar, disculpa que recurra a usted nuevamente, pero son problemas que para usted son fáciles de solucionar. Quiero que los mensajes esten ordenados **DESC** sin importar que el mensaje sea recibido o enviado. Ósea si yo envió un mensaje y la conversación esta de ultimo en la fila, quiero que suba al primer puesto. Y ya por ultimo hay un error en `id_emisor` no me esta mostrando verdaderamente quien envió el mensaje. Dice que lo envió el usuario con ID 2 y en otra conversación dice que el usuario con ID 4 cuando lo envió el usuario 1

Comment: @Sal Es importante saber el **ID** Correcto de quien ha enviado el usuario porque yo tengo una condición que me muestra un `<span>` con el texto **TU:** para decirle al usuario que ese mensaje lo ha enviado el. Pero no puedo hacerlo porque he descubierto el `id_emisor` me esta extrayendo un ID equivocado

Comment: @Braylin : Es simple, para el orden agrega `ORDER BY greatest(ultimo_id_messege_rec,ultimo_id_messege_env) DESC`. El span debes mostrarlo si `ultimo_id_messege_env > ultimo_id_messege_rec`.

Comment: @Sal Ahora si, todo bien. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

No me queda muy claro que es lo que necesitas.

Esta consulta retorna la cantidad de mensajes no leidos por emisor para cada uno de los receptores que haya. Si necesitas la información de un solo receptor deberías filtrar por el receptor.

```
SELECT m.id_receptor, m.id_emisor, u.name, u.surname, u.photo_profile, count(*) AS countMessege
FROM messege m
JOIN users u USING(id_emisor)
WHERE m.view = 'No' 
GROUP BY m.id_receptor, m.id_emisor, u.name, u.surname, u.photo_profile
ORDER BY m.id_receptor, u.surname, u.name
```

Salida (con datos de ejemplo):

```
| id_receptor | id_emisor | name (del emisor) | surname (del emisor) | photo_profile (del emisor) | countMessege |
|:-----------:|:---------:|:-----------------:|:--------------------:|:--------------------------:|:------------:|
|      8      |     15    |        Juan       |         Perez        |       path de la foto      |       3      |
|      8      |     20    |      Roberto      |        Marquez       |       path de la foto      |       1      |
|      32     |     12    |       Carla       |       Martinez       |       path de la foto      |       5      |
```

Comment: Me esta saliendo un error en la linea 69 porque no estoy extrayendo bien los datos de la consulta. Me dice que "$countMessege no definida" ahora te dejo el codigo de la consulta para ver como estoy extrayendo los datos

Comment: `<?php

 // Sacar la cantidad de mensajes no leido
 $stetament = $conexion->prepare(
    "SELECT m.id_receptor, m.id_emisor, u.name, u.surname, u.photo_profile, count(*)
    FROM messege m
    JOIN users u USING(id_emisor)
    WHERE m.view = 'No' 
    GROUP BY m.id_receptor, m.id_emisor, u.name, u.surname, u.photo_profile
    ORDER BY m.id_receptor, m.id_emisor"
);

$stetament->execute(array());
while ($result = $stetament->fetch()) {   
    // cantidad de mensajes no leidos
    $countMessege = $result['id_emisor'];
    $countMessege = (int)$countMessege;
}`

Comment: Mi query no retorna los mismos datos que la tuya, cumple con el objetivo solicitado: "Quiero mostrar la cantidad de mensajes no leídos que tengo en cada conversación". Que campos necesitas que retorne la query? El campo count esta pero no con es nombre, ahora lo voy a arreglar.

Comment: Te recomiendo probar mi query en phpMyAdmin para que compruebes que datos retorna.

Comment: Ya he solucionado la pregunta. De todas formas te agradezco por el interés de solucionarla

Answer (score 0):

## Solución

Con un esquema como el siguiente:

[image: esquema de las tablas]

Puedes obtener todos los mensajes que un usuario no ha visto de la siguiente manera:

```
select id_emisor, count(id_emisor) msg_sin_leer
from messege m
         join users u on :id = m.id_receptor and u.id_user = m.id_emisor and view = 'No'
group by id_user;
```

Con un usuario con `:id = 4` que no haya leído mensajes tendrías la siguiente respuesta

```
+---------+------------+
|id_emisor|msg_sin_leer|
+---------+------------+
|1        |1           |
|6        |2           |
|5        |1           |
+---------+------------+
```

Así que para php solo necesitas interpolar ese valor:

```php
$stetament = $conexion->prepare(
    "select id_emisor, count(id_emisor) msg_sin_leer
from messege m
         join users u on $id = m.id_receptor and u.id_user = m.id_emisor and view = 'No'
group by id_user;"
);
```

#### Más datos

¿Qué pasa si quisiera la información del nombre, apellido y foto de quien me mando mensaje y no solo el id?

Fácil, solo lo agregas esos datos al `select`:

```
select id_emisor, count(id_emisor) msg_sin_leer, name, surname, photo_profile
from messege m
         join users u on :id = m.id_receptor and u.id_user = m.id_emisor and view = 'No'
group by id_user
```

Tenemos una respuesta como la siguiente (`:id = 4`)

```
+---------+------------+----+-----------+---------------+
|id_emisor|msg_sin_leer|name|surname    |photo_profile  |
+---------+------------+----+-----------+---------------+
|1        |1           |UsrA|UsrASurname|www.example.com|
|6        |2           |usrf|usrfsurname|www.example.com|
|5        |1           |usre|usresurname|www.example.com|
+---------+------------+----+-----------+---------------+
```

---

#### Extra

Puedes jugar con un pequeño dataset en [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9af38/2/0)